FIR filter with even-symmetry and odd N taps guaranteed no zero at z=1?
I was given an exercise to prove that there could be no zero for $z=1$ for odd and even symmetric FIR filters with an odd number of $N$ taps. For nonzero coefficients with odd-symmetry this makes a lot of sense (EDIT: This is wrong. See edit below and comments by Matt L.) however for even-symmetry I'm stuck at this point :
$$\begin{align}
H(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]z^{-n} \\
\implies H(z) \Big|_{z=1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n] \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\left(\frac{N-1}{2}-1\right)}h[n] +h\left[\tfrac{N-1}{2}\right]+\sum_{n=\frac{N+1}{2}}^{N-1}h[n] \\
 &=2 \sum_{n=0}^{\left(\frac{N-1}{2}-1\right)}h[n] +h\left[\tfrac{N-1}{2}\right] \\
\end{align} $$
My question is, is there any criteria for coefficient values that restricts the sum of all of the coefficients bar the central value (or equivalently twice the sum of the left side of the coefficient vector), from equaling the negative of the central value, and consequently there being a zero at $z=1$.
I'm thinking this gap in my knowledge is where I'm going wrong but if it isn't, any prods in the right direction are much appreciated.
EDIT:
This question was asked with an improper understanding of odd-symmetry (namely that the central value for an odd-symmetric set must be zero). As such there is always a zero at $z=1$ for odd-symmetric filters and the answer by @Matt L. shows a counter example where there is a zero at $z=1$ for even symmetric filters (i.e. rebutting the premise of the question that there is coefficient criteria that would prohibit this from happening).
(I appreciate the time and patience Matt)

FIR filters with odd symmetry always have a zero at $z=1$. So what do you mean by "For nonzero coefficients with odd-symmetry this makes a lot of sense [...]"?

@MattL. For an odd number of N taps wouldn't an example of an FIR filter with odd-symmetry with no zero at z=1 be $$\left[-\frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Ah, now I understand your misunderstanding. Your example doesn't have odd symmetry. Odd symmetry would mean that the center tap must be zero, otherwise you don't have $h[n]=-h[-n]$ (if we center the impulse response at $n=0$).

Counterexample:
$$h[n]=\left[-\tfrac12,1,-\tfrac12\right]$$
has odd length, even symmetry, and it has a zero at $z=1$.
In general, type I linear-phase FIR filters (even symmetry, odd length) have no constraints on zeros. However, they could have zeros at either $z=1$ or $z=-1$. On the other hand, FIR filters with odd symmetry (type III and IV) always have a zero at $z=1$.
Conclusion: you cannot show that a linear-phase FIR filter with even symmetry and an odd number of taps (type I) is guaranteed to have no zero at $z=1$ because that is not the case, as shown by the counterexample above. Linear-phase FIR filters with odd symmetry always have a zero at $z=1$, regardless of whether their length is even or odd.
Refer to this answer for a discussion of the four types of linear-phase FIR filters.
